# Msaccess cratch : VBA bug related to decimal field

Tags: decimal, recordset

A program of mine has started to crash lately. It is caused by code dealing with recordset which has one decimal field that you wish to use. The code stopped working after 5 years.

My current solution is to change my field type from decimal to currency or double ...  But how come decimal fields caused  VBA to crash... The screen works fine. The query works fine unless I tried to see the value of a specific decimal type field in my VBA coding then Msaccess End without warning !!!

Is someone with better contact, could reach the Microsoft VBA team for this problem?

TO replicate the bug:  table   bugged with field integer AnneeControl, and field decimal   price
a form that show records with the following afterupdate event

Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()

```
Dim mydbs As Database

Dim mystr2 As String

Dim myrst As Recordset

On Error GoTo debugfunction

mystr2 = "SELECT  Bugged.AnneeControl, Bugged.locationPrix FROM Bugged;"

Set mydbs = CurrentDb

Set myrst = mydbs.OpenRecordset(mystr2)

If myrst.RecordCount > 0 Then

    myrst.MoveLast

    myrst.MoveFirst
```

' Microsoft Access  VBA will display the value of the year (AnneeControl Field)
'when your put the mouse cursor over myrst.Fields(1)

```
        MsgBox myrst.Fields(0)
```

' But as soon as you put the mouse over  the next expression
'Microsoft access  will terminate  in a fatal cratch !!!

```
        MsgBox myrst.Fields(1)

End If

Exit Sub
```

debugfunction:

MsgBox Err.Number

End Sub

Here the picture  of my vba screen,  read the text above and below  the myrst.fields(0)

[VBA debug picture of decimal field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBmV6.png)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?812947-Decimal-Point-Crash

I looked through the above thread and think the issue may be related to validation.

It's possible your data source (an untrained user? new input file format?) is filling this column with data that no longer works with your program code, which could explain why it stopped working after 5 years.

In the thread I linked, one forum member says

> "." cannot be represented as a decimal. "0." can and ".0" can, but I
> don't think "." can.

Your next task is to figure out exactly which value causes the application to break when the field type for LocationPrix is set to Decimal. Whoever/whatever is providing you that bogus data will need to be corrected.

You may also want to invest in some error-handling, such as Try/Catch statements or TryParse so that the application doesn't crash if an exception is thrown. Eg.

```
Dim num1 As Decimal
If Decimal.Tryparse(myrst.Fields(0),num1) Then
       'The field contained valid data and is stored in num1. 
Else
       'The field did not contain valid data. Maybe a string, or empty cell. Write some logic here to handle that case
End If
```

Comment: the example table was built by me with only one record with a value 111.34 if you  have this field as decimal  the program crashed if double or currency  the program works...  in the past, the program always works with  decimal field and start crashing a 2 weeks ago. Why dont you try it ? you ll see